# Remove multiples lines of text C#

Tags: c#, regex

I probably titled this incorrectly, but I have a file with multiple lines structured like so:

```
#### ID: 0 NAME: card_inventory ####
{ ALL CONTENT WOULD GO BETWEEN HERE }
#### ENDCARD ####

#### ID: 1 NAME: card_inventory ####
{ ALL CONTENT WOULD GO BETWEEN HERE }
{ I WANT TO REMOVE ALL REFERENCES TO
  THIS CARD WITH AN ID OF 1 }
#### ENDCARD ####
```

So basically my question is how can I located the card id and delete it's contents? I was thinking maybe RegEX, but I'm not sure as I've never attempted this sort of thing before.

==== UPDATE ====

So I sort of have this working, but I've got a new problem, when I call my delete action

```
using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(this.cardinfo_path))
{
    sw.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(this.cardinfo_path,
        @"####\sID:\s(" + id + @")\s.*?####\sENDCARD\s####", "TACO",
        RegexOptions.Singleline));
}
```

It simply add the file name to the end of the file. Where am I going wrong? I feel like such a newbie asking this question.

Comment: Are you wanting to do this in C# or is the language irrelevant?

Comment: I am wanting to do this in c#

Answer (score 1):

Regex may not be the ideal solution, but if your data is structured that cleanly then it will work

```
####\sID:\s(1)\s.*?####\sENDCARD\s####
```

Replace `(1)` with the ID you want to remove.

```
Regex.Replace( filecontents, 
               @"####\sID:\s(" + cardid + @")\s.*?####\sENDCARD\s####",
               "",
               RegexOptions.Singeline );
```

The key to this regular expression is using the [non-greedy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374.aspx) `.*?` match so that it will match the first occurrence of ENDCARD following the id.

Comment: Alright, so I'm going to ask a newbie question and ask what is wrong with my code:
`code
        private void delete_card(int id)
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(this.cardinfo_path))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(this.cardinfo_path,
                    @"####\sID:\s(" + id + @")\s.*?####\sENDCARD\s####", "TACO",
                    RegexOptions.Singleline));
            }
        }
`
I simply appends the file and writes the file name at the end. But doesn't remove the block. I apologize for my ignorance.

Comment: Your passing the file name to Regex.Replace, You need to pass the file contents.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with one loop reading the file, a boolean flag triggered on detection of "#### ID: 1" (and reset on next detection of "####"), and another stream writing to the output file if the boolean flag is true.

The code would look approximately like (hand-written):

```
var reader = new FileReader ("input.cards");
var writer = new FileWriter ("filtered.cards");

var writeToOutput = true;

while (! reader.EndOfStream)
{
    var inputLine = reader.ReadLine ();

    if (inputLine.StartsWith ("####"))
    {
        // control line
        if (inputLine.Contains ("ID: 1"))
            writeToOutput = false;

        if (! writeToOutput && inputLine.Contains ("ENDCARD"))
            writeToOutput = true;
    }

    if (writeToOutput)
        writer.WriteLine (inputLine);
}
```

Comment: You will skip the line opening the cart but emit the ENDCARD line which will probably break the file structure.

Answer (score 0):

May it can be done with a single regex but a little filter should do it as well (also gives you a bit more flexibility in case you want to do something more):

```
bool skipCurrentCart = false;

var cartFileName = "yourcartfile";
var tmpFileName = Path.GetTempFileName();

using (var reader = new StreamReader(cartFileName))
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(tmpFileName))
{
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
         var line = reader.ReadLine();

         if (!skipCurrentCart)
         {
             writer.WriteLine(line);
         }

         if (line.StartsWith(string.Format("#### ID: {0} NAME: card_inventory ####", cartIdToIgnore)))
         {
             skipCurrentCart = true;
         }
         else if (line.StartsWith("#### ENDCARD ####"))
         {
             skipCurrentCart = false;
         }
    }
}

// replace cart file
File.Move(tmpFileName, cartFileName);
```

Comment: @insta: Hehe, yeah I thought so too. Although I think you got a bug in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused by your question. You seem to be wanting to different things. Do you want to remove the card or just its contents. The following will only remove its contents.

`(?<=(#### ID: 1 NAME: card_inventory ####))(.|\n)+?(?=(#### ENDCARD ####))`

Just change the card ID to whatever you need.

Perhaps:

`"(?<=(#### ID: " + cardId + " NAME: card_inventory ####))(.|\n)+?(?=(#### ENDCARD ####))"`

This will only get the data in between excluding the #### stuff.